# How to implement conditional visibility of methods in a Builder design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

How to change the visibility of methods in a Builder design pattern ?

For example I have this Builder :

```
public class Builder {

    public Builder a() {
        //
        return this;
    }

    public Builder b() {
        //
        return this;
    }

}
```

User can use the API and do this :

```
new Builder().a().b();
new Builder().a();
new Builder().b();
new Builder().b().a();
```

I want to allow him to access method `b()` only if `a()` has been called :

```
new Builder().a().b();
new Builder().a();
```

A simple example could be a SQL request Builder. You shouldn't be allowed to call `when()` before `select()`.

How to do so?

Comment: Use a step builder. A blog post worth reading with an illustrative example : [step-builder-pattern](https://medium.com/@castigliego/step-builder-pattern-3bcac4eaf9e8)

Comment: @Eritrean Thank you for your comment. I've read the article andI tried the approach. However, there is one downside doing it this way : I can't implement a method called `and()` in the static `Step` class, even if it's return type isn't the same.

Comment: Instead of `a().isLowerThan().b().and().a().isLowerThan().c()` you should have something like `a.isLowerThan(b) && a.isLowerThan(c)`. Don't overengineer things IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two approaches : *StepBuilder* pattern, mentioned [here](https://rdafbn.blogspot.com/2012/07/step-builder-pattern_28.html) (thanks to *Eritrean*) and a custom one, described after.

---

**StepBuilder**

Inside your builder class, define as many interfaces as "steps" your building should have. The returning type of a method in an interface returns to the type where the next methods should be available.

Here `b()` can only be called after `a()`.

```
public class Builder {
    /*
     * next available methods are defined by 
     * the returned interface type
     */
    private static interface AStep {
        BStep a();
    }

    private static interface BStep {
       void b();
    }

    private static class Steps implements AStep, BStep {
        BStep a() {
            //
            return this;
        }

        void b() {
           //
           return this;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Custom approach with Abstract class** (I call it : the *AbstractBuilder*)

As I couldn't define same methods names with the **StepBuilder** approach I tried something else.

- I defined a main `Builder` with the first callable methods (visible), common methods and the `build()` method (protected, because it will only be availble through other classes if needed).
- I defined an abstract class, called `AbstractBuilder`, with an attribute of `Builder` type and a constructor setting this attribute.
- I defined as many builders as steps I have. All those builders extends `AbstractBuilder` and thus have common methods and ending method available if needed, by calling it on the `Builder` instance.

It looks like this :

```
public class AbstractBuilder {

    protected Builder builder;

    protected AbstractBuilder(Builder builder) {
        this.builder = builder;
    }
}
```

```
public class Builder {

    public BStep a() {
        //
        return new BStep(this);
    }

    protected Object build() {
        // 
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public class BStep extends AbstractBuilder {

    protected BStep(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
    }

    public CStep b() {
        //
        return new CStep(builder);
    }

    public Object build() {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

```
public class CStep extends AbstractBuilder {

    protected CStep(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
    }
    
    public BStep and() {
        //
        return new BStep(builder);
    }

    public DStep c() {
        //
        return new DStep(builder);
    }

    public Object build() {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

```
public class DStep extends AbstractBuilder {

    protected DStep(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
    }
    
    public CStep and() {
        //
        return new CStep(builder);
    }

    public EStep d() {
        // etc. ... return new EStep(builder);
    }

    public Object build() {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

with this pattern you can manage the availability of methods after each calls and use "backwards" loops :

```
Builder builder = new Builder();
builder.a().b().and().a().b().c().and().b().build();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can do this:

```
public class Builder {
    
    private boolean aProcessed;
    
    public Builder() {
        this.aProcessed = false;
    }

    public Builder a() {
        //
        aProcessed = true;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder b() throws IllegalAccessException {
        if (!aProcessed) {
            throw new IllegalAccessException();
        }
        //
        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though this is pretty straightforward, it lets all the methods available to the user. With the *StepBuilder* pattern mentionned above, `b()` is not visible unless `a()` has been called.

Comment: I feel like this is usually the better approach than the step builder, which seems to me to potentially introduce additional complexity by intermediate interfaces without the benefits outweighing it. I'm sure there are valid use cases for that to, but to just ensure method order, KISS.